# input string problem

Tags: java

```
System.out.println("Please enter the required word  :");
    Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    String word2 = scan2.nextLine();
    String[] array2 = word2.split(" ");

    for (int b = 0; b < array2.length; b++) {
        int numofDoc = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < filename; i++) {

            try {

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                        "C:\\Users\\user\\fypworkspace\\TextRenderer\\abc"
                                + i + ".txt"));

                int matchedWord = 0;

                Scanner s2 = new Scanner(in);

                {

                    while (s2.hasNext()) {
                        if (s2.next().equals(word2))
                            matchedWord++;
                    }

                }
                if (matchedWord > 0)
                    numofDoc++;

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("File not found.");
            }

        }
        System.out.println("This file contain the term  " + numofDoc);
    }
}
```

}

this is my code for calculating number of documents containing a specific term. For example :
assume i have 10 million text file and string COW appears in one thousand of these. I am looking for the total one thousand documents containing the COW string.

My program currently only can process one string input.

The output of my program is :

COW

The files containing this term is 1000.

The problem i facing now is when i input 3 strings, It cannot process 3 strings. For example :

COW IS GOOD

The files containing this term is 0.

The files containing this term is 0.

The files containing this term is 0.

I have been trying whole day but i cant see where is my mistake. Mind pointing my mistakes ?

Comment: Do you mean "COW IS GOOD" as a phrase should be found in the files? Or do you mean that any one of "COW", "IS" or "GOOD" should be found?

Comment: What's the use of `String[] array2 = word2.split(" ");` if you're not using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code, you do a loop 3 times (array2.length) but you don't use the array2 at all, instead, you look for the string "COW IS GOOD" three times. you should change the line `s2.next().equals(word2)` to `s2.next().equals(array2[b])`

Comment: lol..thanks..this minor mistake caused me a day...thanks lot !

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here:

```
if (s2.next().equals(word2))
```

if `word2 = "I love you"` and you're doing an `equals()`, `s2.next()` **must** contain the word `I love you`.

One way to solve this.

```
String[] words = word2.split(" ");
for (String word: words) {
    if (s2.next().equals(word)) {
        matchedWord++;
    }
}
```

Comment: And I doubt Scanner.hasNext() gives back a line, by default it breaks the line up in words and COW IS GOOD is not a word :)

Comment: `Scanner.hasNext()`, I think, returns a word. The OP gets a sentence from `String word2 = scan2.nextLine();`. He should just break it into words and validate.